# What can I use for quick temporary storage in PHP

Tags: php, storage

I am creating a small plugin that process some images. Now to report the progress back to the user I have a small ajax script that will long poll the results back.

Now intern I need an object that keeps track of what is processed. Now the options I am aware of are the following.

Using the **PHP session** object. I cannot use this in this specific case, because the initial process is also done by ajax. So the main process is a ajax call, and the long poll ajax is another ajax call. They have 2 different session id's, so they do not communicate well.

Second option is to use the **database** as the storage. I do not know if this is so good because there will be around 40 read / writes on an average job. I know that this is no problem, but it seems a little much for something so simple.

What I actual look for is a sort of memory object if that is possible. Create a small object in the memory that is rapidly updated with the progress and deleted when we are done.

I do not know if that is possible, exists such a thing in PHP, and can I make use of this. Note that this will be a public plugin, so I need to work with methods that are available on all kind of systems, nothing special.

Comment: Maybe [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)? I'm not following your problem with sessions, either.

Comment: Use a cookie (it will be saved local on the clients computer)

Comment: @JaredFarrish session's are saved on the server and it takes a lot time to read and write them

Comment: @micha - Oh I see, it's a session timeout issue. Cookies might be a good option then, or a temporary table. Maybe LocalStorage?

Comment: The problem with the session is that I get 2 different session id's. It took me an hour to figure that out, I was not aware of that problem either, but the session just doesn't work. Two ajax calls generate 2 different session ID's I guess. Further a cookie would be too much.

Comment: @JaredFarrish LocalStorage is Javascript and not PHP ;)

Comment: I do not want to use something that is on the client side such as localStorage or a cookie. I need something that is on the server side, becuase I need rapid updates of the progress on the server side.

Comment: what about logging the progress to a temp log file and let the 2nd ajax calls to read it?

Comment: Can't you make the [session last longer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)?

Comment: @micha - Yes, I know that. `:)`

Comment: I don't relay know if this is possible but you can try it: `define("tempStorage", "data");` and on another page `echo tempStorage;`??? or just post the data with the form if they aren't secure.

Comment: @jared the problem is not the time of the session, it is the session id. They are different, so they do not communicate. Maybe there is a method to have them communicate, i do not know.

Comment: @Jim Jose I do not really understand what you mean. Do you mean writing to a file on the server. I think using the normal database would be a better option still.

Comment: If you use the same browser instance, I don't understand why you could not get the same session id. Could it be because you use different addresses to access the same server? E.g. 'www.mysite.com' versus 'mysite.com'? Maybe take a look at the PHP documentation of ini_set('session.name', ... and ini_set('session.cookie_path', ... to enforce reusing of the same session id.

Comment: No it is really strange, the website is the same, but two different files are accessed. The first script accesses process.php and the other one uses progress.php. Maybe that is the problem. However there is no way to have them call the same file. The system is not set up like that.

Comment: It might help to make sure that the page from which you make the ajax calls has already 'setup' a session. Alternatively, you can  pass on the session id from the result of the first ajax call to the second ajax call, and take over the existing session id by using the function `session_id()`

Comment: @SaifBechan if you write `session_start();` on the beginning of the page every user who enter the page will get a session id. If you set one or two sessions ($_SESSION["one"] = "ok";) doesn't matter because all sessions will be saved in one little text file on the server under read-only access. And no user will get two different session id's!!!

Comment: @the nail this could be an option, but there is a problem in this. I can only return the session id when the process is done. This will make no sense, because I want to report the progress of the process. So when the process is busy, I have no way of knowing what the session ID is.

Comment: Saif, either we're not understanding what you're trying to accomplish, or you're not really understanding what sessions are. Sessions are tied to the *browser*, so they identify a particular requesting client as being unique (using a cookie to set an ID for the browser). A session on the server is a superglobal array. The only reason you would get two IDs from the same browser is if the session expires (or cookies are deleted) and it is reset. But I think we're not really understanding what you're doing. I think you made a good choice to use MySQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think database is not the worse solution. If you think write in disk, maybe can be worse.

Memcache is good, but you need a "external plugins free" small plugin who runs easily on win, linux, mac, and so on... is not a good option.

If you use Mysql, you can use Memory engine tables, witch is fast, and truncate it or clean it periodically, with a simple garbage collector algoritm. And if memory table is not a option, innodb is good enough.

Comment: Yeah I thought memchached would not be the best solution. The memory table looks like a good idea. I will look a little into that. I do not think I need a periodical garbage collector, because I can clean as soon as the script is done running.

Comment: Do you maybe have a good link on how to exactly use memory engine tables.

Comment: The garbage collector can help you with processes or users who leave page/process before they reach the end of processing. It can clean temporary files stored out of operational system temporary folder too.

Comment: To use memory tables just use `CREATE TABLE ( <fields> ) ENGINE=Memory;`, you can [check here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Redis](http://redis.io), *"an open source, advanced key-value store"*, I think you will like it.

You need to run a Redis **server**, and access it with different [clients](http://redis.io/clients). The client of choice for PHP is [Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis). The usage is very simple:

```
 $client = new Predis\Client($single_server);

 $client->set('library', 'predis');
 $retval = $client->get('library');
```

Comment: This would be a great option if my plugin was for personal use. But I am developing a public plugin that will be available for wordpress users. I cannot rely on this, because I do not think many people will have stis available.

Comment: +1 No problem, this is certainly something I can use in my pesonal projects, it's an amazing idea. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You can use memcache for this.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php
As key you can use a md5 hash of the image file plus the users ip.

Comment: Do you think I can rely on this in a public plugin. Is this something that is generally available, or is it something that is only available for certain users.

Comment: Memcache is not available on all PHP servers but it is widely used and many applications rely on it. Your plugin can check if it is available on the server and fallback to using temp files (with the key as filename) if it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Database its not a bad idea when you are useing heap table. Sometimes you simply dont have memcache at server.
Check [Memory Tables at MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html)

Comment: Yes I was thinking the same thing. Maybe use the memcached if available, else fallback on the normal database.

Comment: I think there is no need to check if memcache is available. Read/Write opperations at Memory Tables are almost so fast as memcache is. Do more, write less ;)

Comment: But in terms of proper programming. Is the database meant for something like this. It will be an object that only lasts for a minute, it will not be actual data.

Comment: Database is nothing more than structure that holds data. Memcache is also some kind of database.  Sometimes database is used to store user sessions so why not use it to storing temprorary values. Anyway in my opinion this kind of table is created for such things.

Answer (score 1):

You want *easy*, *highly portable*, shared memory between php processes regardless of how php is installed? use a mysql memory table. php without mysql installed is pretty rare.